Problems with docker and airflow (specifically dockeroperator)
I turn to you to help me to solve a many-days problem. I'm having problems with a specific configuration of airflow in docker. The context is that i am configuring several containers in order to run a DAG with Airflow in Docker. This DAG must runs an ETL process from an API in a specific container. My airflow containers run without problems, but the problem take place when ETL process must run on his container, triggered by the DAG. When DAG is executing DockerOperator, seems that it doesn't work, and in the log, I see the following:

[2024-08-30, 03:25:15 UTC] {docker.py:248} INFO - Starting docker container from image python:3.11.2
[2024-08-30, 03:25:15 UTC] {docker.py:259} WARNING - Using remote engine or docker-in-docker and mounting temporary volume from host is not supported. Falling back to mount_tmp_dir=False mode. You can set mount_tmp_dir parameter to False to disable mounting and remove the warning
[2024-08-30, 03:25:15 UTC] {docker.py:310} INFO - python: can't open file '/app/main_script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[2024-08-30, 03:25:16 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1909} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 268, in _raise_for_status
response.raise_for_status()
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 1022, in raise_for_status
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://host.docker.internal:2375/v1.46/containers/create


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py", line 255, in _run_image
return self._run_image_with_mounts(self.mounts + [tmp_mount], add_tmp_variable=True)
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py", line 300, in _run_image_with_mounts
tty=self.tty,
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 428, in create_container
return self.create_container_from_config(config, name)
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 439, in create_container_from_config
return self._result(res, True)
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 274, in _result
self._raise_for_status(response)
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 270, in _raise_for_status
raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 400 Client Error for http://host.docker.internal:2375/v1.46/containers/create: Bad Request ("invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /tmp/airflowtmpc6w7dat2")

Every answer that I have found hasn't fixed the problem, but many of them says that it could be a problem about the docker daemon and the way that it works. If it so, the problem may be in the file docker.sock, but sincerely I don't know
I also have to say that I'm a beginner with docker and airflow, so my knowledge isn't enough. I have been trying to solve that in a lot of ways but all of attempts have failed.
If you need more information to help me, feel free to ask and I will be greatly grateful.
My docker operator and DAG look like this:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator

default_args = {'owner': 'cristobalqv',
                'retries': 5,
                'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)}

with DAG(default_args=default_args,
         dag_id='etl_meterorologia',
         description='DAG para realizar proceso ETL. extracción desde API, transformación y carga a AWS',
         start_date=datetime(2024,8,27),
         schedule_interval='@hourly') as dag:
    
    #utilizamos dockeroperator para que el contenedor de etl se ejecute unicamente cuando el dag lo requiera
    python_etl_task = DockerOperator(task_id='ejecutar_proceso_etl', 
                                     image='python:3.11.2',   
                                     command='python /app/main_script.py',
                                     docker_url='tcp://host.docker.internal:2375/',  
                                     network_mode='bridge',  
                                     auto_remove=True,
                                     environment={'DATABASE_URL':'postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres:5432/airflow'},
                                     dag=dag)```


This is a Docker in the Docker Scenario, where Airflow runs on Docker. It is a similar case as here.
You can solve this by adding a volume containing the Docker socket from the host to the scheduler container.
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw

Also, the docker_url can be:
docker_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock'


thanks for your answer. I tried to apply your solution and as i see on that link, he fixed his code by applying a wrapper that must be situated on ./script/wrapdocker. Well I must combine your solution with his, and also i have to create a docker.sock file, but this solution is not advisable due to it's not safe. So i don't know how to proceed..
